# iOS animation block: ignores animation commands

Tags: ios, ios5

I'll try to simplify the problem as much as I can.

I have an animation block to animate two UIViewImages.

I take the rectangle of the UIImageViews before I start:

I change: origin.x+=40 for both

In the animation block, I set the frame of those two UIImage views to the modified rectangles.

**It works.**

Now here's a thing. For *one* of the rectangles, I'll also change the size.width-= 20 so that it shrinks a bit in width.

**The Result:** The shrinking and moving takes place, but the second UIImage view will not move anymore. It's as if animating a width/height of an element, cancels out all other animations in the animation block.

I can't figure out why. I've been on this for two days now to no avail. Has anyone ever encountered anything like this? I'm on iOS 5.1 Xcode 4.3.2

Comment: can you show the code please?

Comment: It seems to me that you have got something wrong in your code. Try to add a breakpoint in your animation block, see how the rects change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the frame property can be animated, it is not the recommended way to animate a view.

Instead I suggest that you apply a CGAffineTransform to transform property of the UIImageView.

Here is the Docs link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html

In your case, you would apply a scale and translation transform to your image views.  Keep in mind that if you want to apply two transforms,you will have to combine them into one first.

Comment: Excellent! this is just what I was looking for. I defined all of my transforms with CGAffineTransform and when animated, all worked perfectly together. Move, rotations, scaling etc. Perfect!